# Errors when mapping over an array of objects and introducing a new property - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects and I would like to loop over them and introduce a new property called 'colors' based on the value of 'y'.

The function works fine as expected, however I get some compile errors.

This is my code:

```js
interface IChartData {
  name: string;
  y ? : number;
  isSum ? : boolean;
}

interface IColorChartByValue extends IChartData {
  color: string;
}

const colorChartByValue = (
  data: IChartData[]
): IColorChartByValue[] => {
  return data.map((item: IChartData, index: number, array: IChartData[]) => {
    if (index === 0 || index === array.length - 1) {
      item.color = '#137cbd'
    } else if (item.y >= 0) {
      item.color = '#0F9960'
    } else if (item.y < 0) {
      item.color = '#D9822B'
    }
    return item;
  });
};


const chartData: IChartData[] = [{
    name: 'Base Case',
    y: 100000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 1',
    y: 11500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 2',
    y: 5677,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 3',
    y: -3001,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 4',
    y: 6500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Upside',
    isSum: true,
  },
]

console.log(colorChartByValue(chartData))
```

This is the playground link: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjawCSBhAFo2kARRSRYAbwCgRxEBbaALmAGdJYIBzAbiuAE8A-E3ABXWgCM4PMMwDKYocHEB7ZQBtoicDwC+FChBgIUaLOuWwceSACE+ANURqRaaAA8Y4ACbMMV-EQk5LzI5rBMrOzg3BR6IcrgrMChahb+tg5OLsAAvMAAFLwgXsSITFi4AaUA2gC6vACU5Zhh6XaOztB1uQB8wSAgsNCQIrDgwCUkAHS0iAAO+fmgMLTNlYSlADTAEF7uwmKSsNt4sIh8DBXWgYjdDb39A6DwBbvuuTl5AAzAAD6-O2870+eVO5ymGmikGwwAAtMAAIz3SgDJ4rKYpCy5YAAcgAxAiAMwAdmQ4i8OKKwD0qOer3RfGAPW+wAAZKzAXs3MAAISfYA-dmc9580GwM58CHQKEw+FIx609GY2DY-FfABiAE5NQA2L6U1E0p4vJYM4AAHgFbI5b25oqtQttvP5YMlkI40LhiORVLASrCqrxBE1AA4AExhmwGgZG1FDEZjHYraQxhopnQ8fQgUKJSDJdY3NbXGq1bHVKko1HAGj0Jg4myIZhoTCN6A4za+-hMBFfXu9juGgcDSuomuMXEAdWIcCQajUiPbnYuiIRAFZ+1SdEOQCOBmO61OjLP52HF1Wu8BVzricTt9S77vqHRxzjDzOnPPCWeq8vYYTewid5bhWnb7pO07GHOwAACzfqiy46uuXxAQ+oHPnWACqczMKAexwU8chiEwbAuChvD1PEiTqNAELKBw+TKm0mSdAxBalA0DRAA)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `item` is a `IChartData`, which means it has no property `color`. You will need to make a new object of type `IColorChartByValue` and return that instead.

Comment: I did extend IChartData: interface IColorChartByValue extends IChartData {
  color: string;
}

Comment: `IColorChartByValue` has a `color` property, however inside of the `map()` you're only working with a `IChartData`. You'll need to return a remapped object like this: `{ name: item.name, y: item.y, isSum: item.isSum, color: '#137cbd' }`

Comment: Can you post the solution in code please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript - Map over a collection to add a property to it to change the type of objects within. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59782977/typescript-map-over-a-collection-to-add-a-property-to-it-to-change-the-type-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you map you just mutate an `IChartData` item, but for TypeScript it's still an `IChartData` that doesn't match `IColorChartByValue`. To fix it, you will need to return an `IColorChartByValue` in your map, instead of mutate it:

```js
    return data.map((item: IChartData, index: number, array:IChartData[] ) => {
    if (index === 0 || index === array.length - 1) {
      return {...item , color:'#137cbd'}
    }
    // ...
```

Check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjawCSBhAFo2kARRSRYAbwCgRxEBbaALmAGdJYIBzAbiuAE8A-E3ABXWgCM4PMMwDKYocHEB7ZQBtoicDwC+FChBgIUaLOuWwceSACE+ANURqRaaAA8Y4ACbMMV-EQk5LzI5rBMrOzg3BR6IcrgrMChahb+tg5OLsAAvMAAFLwgXsSITFi4AaUA2gC6vACU5Zhh6XaOztB1uQB8wSAgsNCQIrDgwCUkAHS0iAAO+fmgMLTNlYSlADTAEF7uwmKSsNt4sIh8DBXWgYjdDb39A6DwBbvuuTl5AAzAAD6-O2870+eVO5ymGmikGwwAAtMAAIz3SgDAZDEZjchTbHLaC0YDbFIWBgAcgAxAiAMwAdmQ4i8JL0qKZTxeSxWUz4wB632AADI+YC9m5gABCT7AH4CoXvcWg2BnPgQ6BQmHwpGPVHo0bjMjYqa4-GEsKkslfABiAE5LQA2L6MorAFlgNmGznAAA8kv5greIrl3ulfrFErBSshHGhcMRyMdg2GOqxOJWBOSJvJBEtAA4AEw5mwO5n6LUJzF65N41NE8IkvZIERqSAtVKwQsDHQNaROnjFtOJSDJdY3NbXGq1XLAaqOlGo4A0ehMEk2RDMNCYFfQEmbOP8JgIr4Hg-b5nHgYz1HzxjAEkAdWIcCQajUiK3O4uiIRAFYj46dKeQOeAyXoud5GI+z45q+s67sAn42tS1L-k6SGAdQdBXre97GE+wCUlBs7vrClIHgiSF-tOO7AdeoEPk4z4ACz4ai742t+XxkShlHoYuACqczMKAexMU8chiEwbAuBxvD1PEiTqNAELKBw+TVm0mSdCpQ6lA0DRAA).

Comment: Can I make the function a reusable one where it does not depend on any specific interface but only depends on y and adds color property?

Comment: Mhh yes sure why not?

Comment: Can you give me an example please? Is it like this   const colorChartByValue = <T extends {y?: number; color: string}>(data: T[]): T[] => {

Comment: Please write a new question for this one ;) I would love to answer it ;)

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105460/converting-a-specific-function-to-a-reusable-function-strongly-typed-typescrip