# Converting a specific function to a reusable function strongly typed - Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a piece of code which is tied to a specific interface. The function only accepts data of this specific interface and returns the output. However, I would like to make this function reusable such that it depends only on the value of 'y' and adds 'color' property to the object based on the value of 'y'.

This is the code:

```js
interface IChartData {
  name: string;
  y ? : number;
  isSum ? : boolean;
}

interface IColorChartByValue extends IChartData {
  color: string;
}

const colorChartByValue = (
  data: IChartData[]
): IColorChartByValue[] => {
  return data.map((item: IChartData, index: number, array: IChartData[]) => {
    if (index === 0 || index === array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#137cbd'
      }
    }
    if ((item.y as number) >= 0 && index !== 0 && index !== array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#0F9960'
      }
    }
    if ((item.y as number) < 0 && index !== 0 && index !== array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#D9822B'
      }
    }

    return { ...item,
      color: 'defaultColor'
    }
  });
};


const chartData: IChartData[] = [{
    name: 'Base Case',
    y: 100000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 1',
    y: 11500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 2',
    y: 5677,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 3',
    y: -3001,
  },
  {
    name: 'Waterfall 4',
    y: 6500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Upside',
    isSum: true,
  },
]

console.log(colorChartByValue(chartData))
```

This is the playground linl: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjawCSBhAFo2kARRSRYAbwCgRxEBbaALmAGdJYIBzAbiuAE8A-E3ABXWgCM4PMMwDKYocHEB7ZQBtoicDwC%20FChBgIUaLOuWwceSACE%20ANURqRaaAA8Y4ACbMMV-EQk5LzI5rBMrOzg3BR6IcrgrMChahb%20tg5OLsAAvMAAFLwgXsSITFi4AaUA2gC6vACU5Zhh6XaOztB1uQB8wSAgsNCQIrDgwCUkAHS0iAAO%20fmgMLTNlYSlADTAEF7uwmKSsNt4sIh8DBXWgYjdDb39A6DwBbvuuTl5AAzAAD6-O2870%20eVO5ymGmikGwwAAtMAAIz3SgDAZDEZjchTbHLaC0YDbFIWBgAcgAxAiAMwAdmQ4i8JL0qKZTxei1xtCmfGAiF8ogkcHuPW%20wAAZKLAXs3MAAISfYA-cWS95y0GwM58CHQKEw%20FIx6o9GjcZkbFTDkE5JhUlkr4AMQAnA6AGxfRlFYAssBspYrLk8vmHQXAAA8CrFEre0tV4aVUdl8rBmshHGhcMRyI9g2GxqxOJWlqJ4XJBAdAA4AEwVmzu5n6Q05zGm-N4wvWkl7JAiNSQFqpWC1gY6BrST08etWxKQZLrG5ra41Wq5YDVD0o1HAGj0Jgkmy8tCYfckzZZ-hMBFfS%20Xk-Mm8DdeoreMYAkgDqxDgSDUakRx9PF0RBEAFZrw9HQ7xAB8BifHd3yML8fwrP8NzPYAgOdalqQgz1sKg6g6GfN8P2Mb9gEpZCNwA2FKUvBFsPAtdTxgl84M-JwfwAFgo1EAOdECvno3CmIIncAFU5mYUA9m4p45DEJg2BcQTeHqeJEnUaAIWUDh8iLNpMk6XTZ1KBoGiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```js
function colorChartByValue<T extends {y?: number}>(data: T[]): (T & {color: string})[] {
  return data.map((item, index, array) => {
    // code omitted
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by adding some generics to `IColorChartByValue` and `colorChartByValue`:

```js
type IColorChartByValue<T = IChartData> = T & {    
  color: string;
};

const colorChartByValue = <T extends IChartData>(
  data: T[]
): IColorChartByValue<T>[] => {
  return data.map((item, index, array) => {
    if (index === 0 || index === array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#137cbd'
      }
    }
    if ((item.y as number) >= 0 && index !== 0 && index !== array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#0F9960'
      }
    }
    if ((item.y as number) < 0 && index !== 0 && index !== array.length - 1) {
      return { ...item,
        color: '#D9822B'
      }
    }

    return { ...item,
      color: 'defaultColor'
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would not want any reference to IChartData at all.

Comment: But you check for an `y` parameter. Where should it come from ?

Comment: From the input. The input should be an array and it should definitely have a key “y”. Doenst need to care about other properties